# How to position the VuetifyJS popover component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using VueJS with the VuetifyJS material design components. How to position the [Vuetify popover component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus#example-popover) below the *MORE* button? (Currently it's positioned on the upper left, I guess it's the fall back x=0, y=0.)

Button:

```
<button @click.prevent="openPopover">MORE</button>
```

Popover Vuetify template:

```
 <template>
  <div class="text-xs-center">
    <v-menu
      offset-x
      :close-on-content-click="false"
      :nudge-width="200"
      v-model="menu"
    >
      <v-btn color="indigo" dark slot="activator">Menu as Popover</v-btn>
      <v-card>
        <v-list>
            <v-list-tile-action>
              <v-btn
                icon
                :class="fav ? 'red--text' : ''"
                @click="fav = !fav"
              >
                <v-icon>favorite</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-list-tile-action>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
    </v-menu>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
    <script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      fav: true,
      menu: false,
      message: false,
      hints: true
    })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `offset-y` instead of `offset-x`?

Comment: @Traxo Just tried it, didn't work unfortunately. Still x0,y0

Comment: Try adding `bottom` attribute as well maybe? Could you reproduce it on codepen perhaps?

Comment: Great idea, here it is: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzaRbd?&editors=101 - I think the problem is that I need to have the __activator button__ outside of the <v-menu> - This part is it: `<v-btn color="indigo" dark slot="activator">CUSTOM MENU as Popover</v-btn>`

Comment: I think you are correct, that might be a problem. However I'm not sure if that's supported. From [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus): `Remember to put the element that activates the menu in the activator slot.`. So I believe that anything you do to make it work would be a workaround? Perhaps someone else can confirm. (one of the `v-menu` props is `activator` which indicates that it's possible, but seems not to be working as described)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem by putting the popover code in a drop down menu.
There are also a couple of options in the API to position the content of the menu.

Examples and API: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus

Comment: can you provide an example here?